# When a product of two primitive elements is also primitive?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $K \subseteq L$ be a finite separable field extension. ($K$ is infinite. I do not mind to assume that $K$ is of characteristic zero).

Assume that $a,b \in L$ are two primitive elements for the extension,
namely, $L=K(a)=K(b)$.

> Is there a criterion which tells when $ab$ is also a primitive element for the extension, namely, $L=K(ab)$?

**Remarks:**

(1) By the primitive element theorem, $a+\lambda b$ is also a primitive element,
for infinitely many $K \ni \lambda$'s, but I am asking about the product not about the sum.

(2) In a few examples I have in mind, $ab$ is *not* a primitive element, for example: $a=i,b=-i,K=\mathbb{R},L=\mathbb{C}$; 
$a=\sqrt2,b=-\sqrt2,K=\mathbb{Q},L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$;
$a=\frac{-1+\sqrt3 i}{2},b=-\frac{-1-\sqrt3 i}{2},K=\mathbb{Q},L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3 ,i)$. Those extensions are splitting fields of $t^2+1$, $t^2-2$, $t^2+t+1$, respectively; I guess that in order to find extensions with $a,b,ab$ primitive higher degrees polynomials are required.

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** (1) I have just found [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404902001962), which may help (though it deals with $K$ finite).
(2) Perhaps [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157784/can-we-always-find-a-primitive-element-that-is-a-square/157956#157956) is relevant.
(3) The comments for [this quetion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391917/is-there-a-general-algorithm-to-find-a-primitive-element-of-a-given-finite-exten?rq=1) probably show that the answer of Lubin is the best answer I can get.

Comment: An example where the product of primitives is also primitive: If $\omega$ is a primitive 5th root of unity, $\omega^5 = 1$, then so are $\omega^2$ and $\omega^3 = \omega \times \omega^2$.

Comment: Thank you! (Truly, I also have seen this example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have trouble getting a useful, very general, statement. Remember this:

If $k\subset K$, say a finite separable extension, then in some rough sense, *almost every* element of $K$ will be primitive for the extension. That is, in such an extension, you don’t have trouble finding a primitive element, you have trouble finding a *non-primitive* element outside $k$. From this fact, I think that it’s still true that if $a$ is primitive for $K\supset k$, almost every choice of a primitive $b$ will make $ab$ primitive.

Comment: Thank you. So perhaps I should ask for a criterion for non-primitive $ab$?

Comment: Well, beyond the definition, namely that $z$ is non-primitive exactly when $z$ is in a proper subfield of $K$, I can’t think of anything.

Comment: Is there a way to find all intermediate fields of a given finite separable field extension $k \subset K$? (If I am not wrong, such an extension has only finitely many intermediate fields)

Comment: Of course, if it is of prime degree then there are no $k \subsetneq \tilde{k} \subsetneq K$.

Comment: How to find all intermediate fields? Easy, if your extension is Galois, ’cause they correspond to proper subgroups of the Galois group. If not Galois, you need to pass to the Galois closure, and apply the same principle. Example: $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3\,)\supset\Bbb Q$, where there are only the three intermediate fields, generated by $\sqrt2$, $\sqrt3$, and $\sqrt6$ respectively. These correspond to the three proper subgroups of $C_2\oplus C_2$, where $C_2$ is a group of order two.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.